# iOS 15: Navigation link popping out, again

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

In the last few months, many developers have reported NavigationLinks to unexpectedly pop out and some workarounds have been published, including adding another empty link and adding .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()) to the navigation view.

Here, I would like to demonstrate another situation under which a NavigationLink unexpectedly pops out:

When there are two levels of child views, i.e. *parentView* > *childLevel1* > *childLevel2*, and childLevel2 modifies childLevel1, then, after going back from level 2 to level 1, level 1 pops out and parentView is shown.

I have filed a bug report but not heard from apple since. None of the known workarounds seem to work. Does someone have an idea what to make of this? Just wait for iOS 15.1?

Below is my code (iPhone app). In the parent view, there is a list of persons from which orders are taken. In childLevel1, all orders from a particular person are shown. Each order can be modified by clicking on it, which leads to childLevel2. In childLevel2, several options are available (here only one is shown for the sake of brevity), which is the reason why the user is supposed to leave childLevel2 via "< Back".

```
import SwiftUI

struct Person: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    var orders: [Order]
}

struct Pastry: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

struct Order: Hashable {
    var paId: Int
    var n: Int // used only in the real code
}

class Data : ObservableObject {
    
    init() {
        pastries = [
            Pastry(id: 0, name: "Prezel"),
            Pastry(id: 1, name: "Donut"),
            Pastry(id: 2, name: "bagel"),
            Pastry(id: 3, name: "cheese cake"),
        ]

        persons = [
            Person(id: 0, name: "Alice", orders: [Order(paId: 1, n: 1)]),
            Person(id: 1, name: "Bob", orders: [Order(paId: 2, n: 1), Order(paId: 3, n: 1)])
        ]
        
        activePersonsIds = [0, 1]
    }
    
    @Published var activePersonsIds: [Int] = []
    @Published var persons: [Person] = []
    @Published var pastries: [Pastry]
    @Published var latestOrder = Order(paId: 0, n: 1)
            
    lazy var pastryName: (Int) -> String = { (paId: Int) -> String in
        if self.pastries.first(where: { $0.id == paId }) == nil {
            return "undefined pastryId " + String(paId)
        }
        return self.pastries.first(where: { $0.id == paId })!.name
    }
    
    var activePersons : [Person] {
        return activePersonsIds.compactMap {id in persons.first(where: {$0.id == id})}
    }
}

@main
struct Bretzel_ProApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @StateObject var data = Data()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView1(data: data)
        // in the real code, there are more tabs
    }
}

struct TabView1: View {
    @StateObject var data: Data

    var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    ForEach(data.activePersons, id: \.self) { person in
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: EditPerson(data: data, psId: person.id),
                            label: {
                                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                                    Text(person.name)
                                }
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
                .navigationTitle("Orders")
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct EditPerson: View {
    @ObservedObject var data: Data
    
    var psId: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        let pindex: Int = data.persons.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == psId })!
        let p: Person = data.persons[pindex]

        List() {
            ForEach (0...p.orders.count-1, id: \.self) { loop in
                Section(header:
                            HStack() {
                                Text("BESTELLUNG " + String(loop+1))
                            }
                ) {
                    EPSubview1(data: data, psId: psId, loop: loop)
                }
            }
        }.navigationTitle(p.name)
        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
    }
}

struct EPSubview1: View {
    @ObservedObject var data: Data
    var psId: Int
    var loop: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        let pindex: Int = data.persons.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == psId })!
        let p: Person = data.persons[pindex]
        let o1: Order = p.orders[loop]

        NavigationLink(
            destination: SelectPastry(data: data)
                .onAppear() {
                    data.latestOrder.paId = o1.paId
                }
                .onDisappear() {
                    data.persons[pindex].orders[loop].paId = data.latestOrder.paId
                },
            label: {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(String(o1.n) + " x " + data.pastryName(o1.paId))
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

struct SelectPastry: View {
    @ObservedObject var data : Data
    
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(data.pastries, id: \.self) {pastry in
                    Button(action: {
                        data.latestOrder.paId = pastry.id
                    }) {
                        Text(pastry.name)
                            .foregroundColor(data.latestOrder.paId == pastry.id ? .primary : .secondary)
                    }
                }
            }.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your `ForEach`. Despite that fact that `Person` conforms to `Identifiable`, you're using `\.self` to identify the data. Because of that, every time an aspect of the `Person` changes, so does the value of `self`.

Instead, just use this form, which uses the `id` vended by `Identifiable`:

```
ForEach(data.activePersons) { person in
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
ForEach(data.activePersons, id: \.id) { person in
```

Comment: Wow, jnpdx, you are my hero! Indeed, this was the solution, although I have no idea how you figured that out just a few minutes after I posted my code. Thanks!

Comment: As soon as I saw `self` being used as an `id`, I had a pretty good idea -- that's an issue that comes up on SO on a somewhat regular basis in a variety of different situations.

Comment: great find. This solutions still works well.